Does it really matter to include or exclude critical points in the Intervals of "Increasing and Decreasing" of a function?


Does it really matter to include or exclude critical points in the Intervals of "Increasing and Decreasing" of a function?


Suppose if we have $f(x)=x^2-5x+6$. Should we say $f$ is strictly increasing in the interval $[2.5, \infty)$ or $(2.5, \infty)$ or anything is fine?

What does it mean for the function to be strictly increasing on $[a,b)$?  We assume the question intends for you to give the largest possible intervals; obviously, it’s increasing on $(3,7)$, as well. What’s your answer, by the way, for $f(x)=x^3$?

This 29 December 2008 sci.math post contains some things that may help. Also, keep in mind @Ted Shifrin's comment that one usually gives the largest possible intervals of increase/decrease.
